# failed to start resolvconf-pull-resolved.service

Tags: login

After updating and upgrading and restarting Ubuntu
I can not login
And I checked the errors and I get this message that it repeats

failed to start resolvconf-pull-resolved.service
Please help me

Comment: Hitting the same error message. My root file system is getting filled with messages in syslog. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I disabled systemd-networkd and started networkmanager in my machine. Deleted /var/log/syslog to free disk space.  I don't see the error message now. But Network is not available during startup.  I manually ran commands to bring network up for now.

ip link set dev eth0 down
dhclient eth0
ip link set dev eth0 up

There seems to be different issue. But this was a good workaround for me to bring my system upto speed and running.

For detailed troubleshooting and permanent fix, we need to do a systemctl level debugging on the network.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall resolvconf with:

```
apt-get remove resolvconf
```

in ubuntu recovery mode(press shift when starting, then go advanced options, then ubuntu(recovery mode), go to root)

[This is a bug](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-rc@lists.debian.org/msg571579.html) , and should be fixed in the latest version of
resolvconf.

> We believe that the bug you reported is fixed in the latest version of
> resolvconf, which is due to be installed in the Debian FTP archive.